# MySQL - Log ALL Connect, SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE and Replies?

Tags: mysql

I know how to enable logging in MySQL and that is showing the connect, select, insert, update and delete commands being run, but what it doesn't show is the results of this or the replies to the commands.

Purely for testing is it possible to log this ?

So a select statement is run and I see the select statement and the resulting reply whether it is from local SQL DB or following connection to a remote one ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the resulting reply whether it is from local SQL DB or following connection to a remote one", e.g. what exactly are you trying to log? Do you have a server and want to log everything it sends to its users, or do you have an app that connects to different servers and want to log everything it receives? What do you consider a result of an insert/update? The number of rows/error/... or the actual rows that were modified? For modified rows, you may want to look at the [binary logs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log.html). The rest won't happen out-of-the-box.

Comment: @Solarflare thanks for the reply.  I have an issue with sync between to application. They both use MySQL and run on different servers. Everything works fine during the day, but at some point either A reads from B or B pushes to A and some details change in A.  I was hoping to enable logging and see what queries A runs and what B returns and vis versa.   Thanks

Comment: If you control the sync app, I would investigate/log there. Apart from connection losses (which are a good indicator for problems on their own), the servers tell the app exactly if a query was successful or not and how many rows were affected, and you already know which query/data you send from your sync app. These seems to be exactly what you want to know (and what you cannot easily get on the server side). You may also want to describe the problem itself, maybe someone has an idea (but you would need to share details about your setup and preferably your app code)